# C print whole string variable (ignore \0 termination)

Tags: c, variables, printf, null-terminated

An example says more than thousand words:

```
unsigned char *hello = (unsigned char*)malloc(STR_LEN * sizeof(unsigned char));
const char *str= "haha";
memcpy(hello, str, strlen(str) + 1);
```

How can I print the content of the whole `hello`-variable (`printf("%s",..)` would only respect the part before the `\0`-termination and not all `STR_LEN` characters).

Comment: Doing so would be undefined behaviour, because the memory isn't initialized.

Comment: I know... And in a normal situation it would not make any sense. But I have to compare some ASM operations and want to compare the bits behind the `\0`.

Comment: Sense or not, its still UB.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I guess debuggers must crash left and right then, no?  In fact UB is a theoretical concept, on practical systems the outcomes are reasonably constrained.

Comment: The more interesting issue here may be that if the desire is to compare "the bits behind" then one probably does not want to print the bytes as ASCII characters, but rather to print out their values in some convenient form, such as hex.

Comment: @ChrisStratton hard to argue with UB being theoretical, since assigning definition to the U is an oxymoron. And who said anything about *crashing* when invoking UB? That would be... expecting definition from the undefined. Like it or not, the standard itself is clear on evaluating uninitialized data. The behavior cannot be relied on, as there is no definition. That a process *doesn't* crash is misplaced assumption that *observed* behavior is therefore *defined*. And nothing is further from reality.

Comment: @WhozCraig - your ceaseless harping on the theoretical concept ignores the practical reality that real programs running on real systems read uninitialized data **all the time**.  Programs do not run on theoretical systems, they run on real ones, which have *well known* behavior that differs from that of language standards.  **Investigative programs** in particular, **such as being discussed here** routinely examine **actual behavior** as distinct from theoretical standards.  Yes, it's undefined behavior, but flying monkeys are not going to enslave you to maintain  their cobol payroll database.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I can only hope your closing sentence is true =). But I guess i'll never really know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `fwrite` to write unformatted data:

```
char buf[4] = { 1, 2 };

fwrite(buf, 1, 4, stdout);   // writes the bytes 1, 2, 0, 0
```

You could use `fwrite(hello, 1, STR_LEN, stdout)`, but note that you're not allowed to read uninitialized data (so you should use `calloc` instead or initialize the data in some other way).

Comment: +1 for being the uninitialized data evaluation police. (somebody has to do it).

Comment: The real problem likely to be encountered on *actual systems* is not with *reading* uninitialized data, but with sending it *unfiltered* to the terminal.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: `| hexdump -C` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write your own for loop that goes from hello to hello+STR_LEN, and prints each character one at a time.

```
for (unsigned char *c = hello, e = hello +STR_LEN; c < e; ++c) {
    printf("%c", *c);
}
```

Comment: No, you wouldn't, as others have pointed out.  However, if the goal is actually to look at the raw data itself, where a character representation is not very userful, then something like this with a format string such as `%02x ` might be a good start for generating an informative little hex dump

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < STR_LEN; i++) {
    putchar(hello[i]);
}
```